# Dropping specific elements from lists

Tags: python

I have data stored in the list. Below you can see my data.

```
listName = ['column1','column2','column3','column4']
```

Now I want to drop elements with titles `'column2'` and  `'column3'`

I tried this command but is not work.

```
listName=listName.drop(['column2','column3'],axis=1)
```

Can anybody help me how to solve this problem?

Comment: What do you mean data stored in the list? You only have strings in a list?

Comment: Yes only strings I have

Comment: So you want to remove elements from the list?

Comment: Two elements 'column2' and 'column3'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to remove them by value, I would create a list of elements to remove and filter the former list via list-comprehension:

```
to_remove = ['column2','column3']

filtered = [x for x in listName if x not in to_remove]
```

Returning:

```
['column1','column4']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try [list.remove()](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html?highlight=list.remove(x)#:%7E:text=append(x).-,list.remove(x),-Remove%20the%20first) to drop elements from a list using the below code

```
listName = ['column1','column2','column3','column4']

try:
    listName.remove("column1")
except ValueError:
    print("Element not found!")
#Output: ['column2', 'column3', 'column4']
```

Handle exceptions if the element does not exist in the list

```
try:
    listName.remove("column5")
except ValueError:
    print("Element not found!")
#Output: Element not found!
```